# MVC version 3 get single model value in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am attempting to make a decision based on values in a table.  I am having difficulty getting a single answer.  This is what i have attempted.

```
var open = from a in db.checkinhours
           where a.location == "Canyon" && a.day == day && a.opentime <= time && a.closetime >= time
           select a;

if (open == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Closed");
}
```

I just need to know if the row exists based on a given set of criteria, but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming your LINQ is returning some enumerable, open.Any() should tell you if you have any results, rather than checking for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open will just be an expression tree.  You might want to do

```
if(open.FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Closed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!db.checkinhours.Any(a => 
a.location == "Canyon" && 
a.day == day 
&& a.opentime <= time 
&& a.closetime >= time))
       return RedirectToAction("Closed");
```